# Как заставить intellij Idea компилировать только необходимые классы а не весь проект?

Tags: intellij-idea

Проблема в следующем, для сохранения шаблонов кода использую один проект с множеством папок. Когда проверяю новый код компилятор компилирует весь огромный проект, хотя части в нем абсолютно не взаимосвязаны. В еклипсе к примеру такого не происходит, поэтому запуск приложений выполняется быстрее. Что нужно настроить, чтобы компилировался и выполнялся локальный код и классы с ним связанные, а не весь проект целиком?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ctrl + shift + F10 по умолчанию запускает текущий открытый исполняемый класс. А кнопка Run работает с последним скомпилированным проектом.

Не хочешь с клавишами дружить, нажимай ПКМ на любом месте класса, который надо запустить, и там уже выбирай Run.